# .R file not updating

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

At wit's end. I think I've tried everything:

I have tried the following:

- Changed workspaces and moved project.
- Cleaned project.
- Deleted entire project.
- Restarted Eclipse.
- Restarted the computer.
- Checked for updates.
- Deleted .R file.
- Deleted import android.R;
- Added import android.R;
- Run the project, it doesn't compile.
- Checked all of my string files.
- Checked all of my .xml files.
- Checked the AndroidManifest.xml
- Built the project by adding the .xml before the code constructing the UI element (a button).
- Built the project by constructing the Button in code first then .xml
- Built the project by dragging the Button on to the graphical layout then referencing that id.
- Desperately wrote code into the .R file - it just rebuilt itself without adding the new Button.

  ```
  public class ButtonActivity extends Activity {
      int count = 0; 

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);

          final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
          final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

          button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  button.setText("Got Pressed:" + ++count);
              }
          });
      }
  }
  ```

I got following error:

> button1 cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Below is the Button in the .xml file.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

I haven't asked God yet, but I think you'll give the more practical response.

Comment: post all your code please, like layout XML file, activity.java file,etc.

Comment: You havent got @+id/button

Comment: There is only one button in xml. But you have instantiated two buttons? why?

Comment: `final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);` it is confusing that your **button2** has R.id. **button1**

Comment: If you cleaned the project and this is still missing, what **is** in your R.java then?  Is the xml file in the right place?

Comment: I sometimes had similar problems with eclipse too. Try to rename your ids in xml to "button_1" "button_2" (just so it changes to something not yet used), save the file, and try finding it code.

Comment: Main.xml did not indicate any errors, but I didn't know that it could have problems without seeing an error. The .R file just skipped over the code that it didn't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check all of your XML,

Project -> Clean,

**Right click -> Fix Project Properties** (do this after the above)
(on the project name in the right column in eclipse)

Keep calm and chive on.

Comment: The .xml file did have an error; the .R file just skipped over it rather than telling me about it.

Answer (score 0):

Import com.thenode.mobile.R; …i.e, your package namespace and your R
file should be regenerated on the next build of your project. If it
still doesn’t work, you definitely, absolutely have an error in one of
your external resource XML files – in this case, my maingui.xml file.
Check your external XML files closely. The reason I think this happens
is that whatever process auto-generates R.java file starts at the top of
your resources and works it’s way down to the bottom. If it encounters
an error somewhere along the way, it just stops – leaving whatever
resources haven’t been added to R.java out but neglecting to tell you
why R cannot be resolved. I think this is why some of them will say
“unresolved”, and others will be fine. Anyway, that’s basically the
three things you should search for when getting this error.

from: http://joshua14.homelinux.org/blog/?p=1202